# Formula to automatically distribute an amount across multiple cells where the max value of each cell and the order of distribution can be defined

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

EXCEL Question: I have 5 cells that I need to distribute the sum 1,000 into. I need to do this in a specific order (the 5 cells each have a numerical value that I can can be used to order the distribution), and to a defined maximum for each cell. The outcome would look something like this:

Cell 1: receives 400 to reach its maximum.
Cell 2: receives 150 to reach it's maximum.
Cell 3: receives 50 to reach it's maximum.
Cell 4: receives 200 to reach it's maximum.
Cell 5: receives the remaining 200, but doesn't reach it's maximum.

I have 25+ sums that I need to distribute to 25+ groups of cells to defined maximums for each cell.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It would be useful to see sample data and the expected outcome

Comment: yes, sample data showing several cases would be helpful. But already ordering 5 items yields 120 different potential orderings. While this may still be manageable, I have a hard time seeing how one would avoid circular referencing using formulas and your expected output. Right now I can only visualize a VBA solution. Good luck...

Comment: Could you provide a sample here?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSaEP.png) is what you are looking to do, but you can put your numbers in the first column and max for that column in the first row, and use:

```
=LET(r,$A2-SUM($A$1:A$1),IF(r>B$1,B$1,IF(r>0,r,0)))
```

or

```
=IF($A2-SUM($A$1:A$1)>B$1,B$1,IF($A2-SUM($A$1:A$1)>0,$A2-SUM($A$1:A$1),0))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).